# page-number-citation add f. or ff

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

is there a possibility to add an f. for "following" or ff. for "and the following" to a fo:page-number-citation if the referenced element goes over several pages?

```xml
<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="123" />
```

Result should be: Page 6f. if the element with id 123 is on page 6-7 or Page 6ff when the element is on page 6-minimum 8.

Comment: It's not part of the XSL 1.1 Recommendation. If you were using AH Formatter, you could use `merge-sequential-page-numbers` (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-ext.html#axf.merge-sequential-page-numbers). FOP doesn't have a similar extension.

Comment: but isnt there any workaround? I tried getting the `fo:page-number-citation` of the first and the last element but there ist no way to do some calculations with it like getting the range and check if its bigger than 1, because it only gets resolved when processing the FOP

Comment: Sorry, no.  The closest thing to a workaround would be to export the FOP area tree, manipulate that, and then format it.  FWIW, calculations with page numbers was in the XSL 2.0 Requirements document: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N66412